# Should I check-In android support library project appcompat to repository?

Tags: android, bitbucket, android-appcompat

I am using ADT for android development.

When we create a new android project example ProjectABC, a appcompat_v7 project is automatically created with it.

I understand that it is created for providing the backward compatibility for the older versions of android.

My question is:

If I am using bitbucket as a repository, I add ProjectABC to the repository. Do I also need to add the appcompat_v7 project to the repository? If yes, then I be adding two different projects?

Thanks
Raja